# Why does a resistance-to-voltage converter use an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, converter

Why do you need to use an op-amp instead of just using I×R=V?

Answer (score 1):

Because of impedance, the opamp offers a high impedance so the low current won't affect the resistance (usually small currents) measurement.

Answer (score 0):

An op-amp can be configured to supply the resistor with a constant current hence, the voltage across the resistor is directly proportional to resistance and not some awkward non-linear relationship that you would get when using a simple potential divider.